# I want to reflect the dark mode and light mode of Google Maps in real-time, but I can't do it

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am displaying Google Maps using Flutter, and I want to change the appearance of the Google Map when the device's appearance mode is changed. But, the `onMapCreated` property of Google Maps is not being executed. How can I change the appearance of the Google Map when the app returns from the background?

I have successfully achieved synchronizing the theme of the app itself with the device's appearance settings and updating it when returning from the background. However, I am currently unable to change the mapStyle of Google Maps.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MapSample(),
    );
  }
}

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapSample({super.key});
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  late Brightness justBeforeMode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {
      justBeforeMode = ui.window.platformBrightness;
    }
    if (AppLifecycleState.resumed == state) {
      if (ui.window.platformBrightness != justBeforeMode) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ui.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.light
          ?
          // lightMode
          GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
            )
          :
          // darkMode
          GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                final darkGoogleMapStyle = await rootBundle
                    .loadString('assets/jsons/dark_map_style.json');
                await controller.setMapStyle(darkGoogleMapStyle);
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Someone asked a similar question here, but I couldn't find a solution:

[flutter google maps update map style in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943230/flutter-google-maps-update-map-style-in-runtime)

Comment: cool question. check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232070/how-to-implement-dark-mode-and-light-mode-in-flutter

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While I have achieved synchronizing with the device's dark mode and light mode settings, I am actually asking a question because I am unable to synchronize the style of Google Maps with the device's settings.